# MongoDB queries with dynamic field names

Tags: typescript, mongodb

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
async getTrack(id, type: String) : Promise<Track[]> {
const query = this.trackModel.find(
    { type : id },
    {_id:0}
).limit(100);
return query;
}
```

In the query I'm trying to make it such that the property "type" name is replaced by the string passed into the function at runtime. Any tips on how to do this?

I did look up on google tried to cast it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
async getTrack(id, type: String) : Promise<Track[]> {
const query = await this.trackModel.find( // add `await` to wait for the answer before returning
    {}, // find all
    {type: "$_id", _id:0} // project `_id` value as `type`, don't project `_id`
).limit(100); // return only 100 documents
return query;
}
```

Or return the query results directly: `return this.trackModel.find(...`

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Glsajvx1qpJ)